# How can I apply a filter to a nested resource in Django REST framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In my app I have the following models:

```
class Zone(models.Model):
    name = models.SlugField()

class ZonePermission(models.Model):
    zone = models.ForeignKey('Zone')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    is_administrator = models.BooleanField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField()
```

I am using Django REST framework to create a resource that returns zone details plus a nested resource showing the authenticated user's permissions for that zone.  The output should be something like this:

```
{
    "name": "test", 
    "current_user_zone_permission": {
        "is_administrator": true, 
        "is_active": true
    }
}
```

I've created serializers like so:

```
class ZonePermissionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ZonePermission
        fields = ('is_administrator', 'is_active')

class ZoneSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    current_user_zone_permission = ZonePermissionSerializer(source='zonepermission_set')

    class Meta:
        model = Zone
        fields = ('name', 'current_user_zone_permission')
```

The problem with this is that when I request a particular zone, the nested resource returns the ZonePermission records for **all** the users with permissions for that zone.  Is there any way of applying a filter on `request.user` to the nested resource?

BTW I don't want to use a `HyperlinkedIdentityField` for this (to minimise http requests).

## Solution

This is the solution I implemented based on the answer below.  I added the following code to my serializer class:

```
current_user_zone_permission = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_user_zone_permission')

def get_user_zone_permission(self, obj):
    user = self.context['request'].user
    zone_permission = ZonePermission.objects.get(zone=obj, user=user)
    serializer = ZonePermissionSerializer(zone_permission)
    return serializer.data
```

Thanks very much for the solution!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I'm faced with the same scenario. The best solution that I've found is to use a `SerializerMethodField` and have that method query and return the desired values. You can have access to `request.user` in that method through `self.context['request'].user`.

Still, this seems like a bit of a hack. I'm fairly new to DRF, so maybe someone with more experience can chime in.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  Can a `SerializerMethodField` return a structure or just a flat field?

Comment: It can return a structure.

Comment: I'll have a go this approach - thanks.  If no other 'official' suggestions come through I'll accept this as the answer.

Comment: Your suggestion worked, thanks!  I've added the code I used in my serializer as an edit on my question above.

Answer (score 10):

You have to use filter instead of get, otherwise if multiple record return you will get Exception.

```
current_user_zone_permission = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_user_zone_permission')

def get_user_zone_permission(self, obj):
    user = self.context['request'].user
    zone_permission = ZonePermission.objects.filter(zone=obj, user=user)
    serializer = ZonePermissionSerializer(zone_permission,many=True)
    return serializer.data
```

Answer (score 5):

Now you can subclass the ListSerializer, using the method I described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28354281/3246023

> You can subclass the ListSerializer and overwrite the to_representation method.
>
> By default the to_representation method calls data.all() on the nested queryset. So you effectively need to make data = data.filter(**your_filters) before the method is called. Then you need to add your subclassed ListSerializer as the list_serializer_class on the meta of the nested serializer.
>
> 1. subclass ListSerializer, overwriting to_representation and then calling super
> 2. add subclassed ListSerializer as the meta list_serializer_class on the nested Serializer

Comment: I also like this method better, as it still allows to keep the field writable if you need so.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using the QuerySet / filter in multiple places, you could **use a getter function on your model**, and then even drop the 'source' kwarg for the Serializer / Field. **DRF automatically calls functions/callables if it finds them** when using it's [get_attribute](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/ba951f333988972392c5925070a2b980535cf930/rest_framework/fields.py#L55) function.

```
class Zone(models.Model):
    name = models.SlugField()

    def current_user_zone_permission(self):
        return ZonePermission.objects.get(zone=self, user=user)
```

I like this method because it keeps your API consistent under the hood with the api over HTTP.

```
class ZoneSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    current_user_zone_permission = ZonePermissionSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Zone
        fields = ('name', 'current_user_zone_permission')
```

Hopefully this helps some people!

*Note: The names don't **need** to match, you can still use the source kwarg if you need/want to.*

*Edit: I just realised that the function on the model doesn't have access to the user or the request. So perhaps a custom model field / ListSerializer would be more suited to this task.*

Answer (score 2):

I would do it in one of two ways.

1) Either do it through prefetch in your view:

```
    serializer = ZoneSerializer(Zone.objects.prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('zone_permission_set', 
            queryset=ZonePermission.objects.filter(user=request.user), 
            to_attr='current_user_zone_permission'))
        .get(id=pk))
```

2) Or do it though the .to_representation:

```
class ZoneSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Zone
        fields = ('name',)

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        data = super(ZoneSerializer, self).to_representation(obj)
        data['current_user_zone_permission'] = ZonePermissionSerializer(ZonePermission.objects.filter(zone=obj, user=self.context['request'].user)).data
        return data
```