# Design history tracking database using django-rest-framework

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am using the django-rest-framework api for the first time. Here's my question:

I need to design a database in which there are two tables:

1. Server => To save the server information such as ip address and server name

`id: INT, name: VARCHAR, ip_address: VARCHAR`

1. Deploy => The deploys on the server including the deploy date and a comment message

`id: INT, server_id: FK to Server, deploy_date: DATETIME, message: VARCHAR`

I am asked to keep track of the deploy information and design the following APIs:

```
get /servers/ => get all the server information with the latest deploy on that server
Example:
[
  {
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "qa-001",
    "ip_address" : "192.168.1.1",
    "deploy" : 
    {
      "id" : 1,
      "deploy_date" : "2013-09-09 12:00:00",
      "message" : "test new api"
    }
  },
  {
    "id" : 2,
    "name" : "qa-002",
    "ip_address" : "192.168.1.2",
    "deploy" : 
    {
      "id" : 2,
      "deploy_date" : "2013-09-10 12:00:00",
      "message" : "test second message"
    }
  }
]

get /deploys/ => get all the deploy information
Example:
[
  {
    "id" : 1,
    "deploy_date" : "2013-09-09 12:00:00",
    "message" : "test new api",
    "server_id" : 1
  },
  {
    "id" : 2,
    "deploy_date" : "2013-09-10 12:00:00",
    "message" : "test second message",
    "server_id" : 2 
  },
  {
    "id" : 3,
    "deploy_date" : "2013-09-08 12:00:00",
    "message" : "test new api",
    "server_id" : 1
  }
]
// Deploy 3 does not show up in the get servers return json 
// because deploy 1 was deployed on the same server but later than deploy 3.

POST /deploys/ => To insert a new deploy
POST /servers/ => To insert a new server
...
```

I have played around with django-rest-framework tutorial code and read about different api documentations but couldn't figure out how to implement the features that I list above.

Please let me know if you have any ideas on how to implement this or if you think another database design would fit this requirement more.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found this question which is very similar to mine.
[How can I apply a filter to a nested resource in Django REST framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16821684/how-can-i-apply-a-filter-to-a-nested-resource-in-django-rest-framework)

And I solved my problem by using the `SerializerMethodField`