# How do you filter a nested serializer in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In Django Rest Framework, how do you filter a serializer when it's nested in another serializer?

My filters are imposed in the DRF viewsets, but when you call a serializer from inside another serializer, the viewset of the nested serializer never gets called, so the nested results appear unfiltered.

I have tried adding a filter on originating viewset, but it doesn't seem to filter the nested results because the nested results get called as a separate pre-fretched query. (The nested serializer is a reverse lookup, you see.)

Is it possible to add a get_queryset() override in the nested serializer itself (moving it out of the viewset), to add the filter there? I've tried that, too, with no luck.

This is what I tried, but it doesn't even seem to get called:

```
class QuestionnaireSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    edition = EditionSerializer(read_only=True)
    company = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Questionnaire

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = super(QuestionnaireSerializer, self).get_queryset(instance)
        if not self.request.user.is_staff:
            query = query.filter(user=self.request.user, edition__hide=False)
        return query
```

Comment: `get_queryset` is a class on `ModelViewSet`, not on the Serializer, which is why it's not getting called

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You can subclass the [ListSerializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#listserializer) and overwrite the `to_representation` method.

By default the `to_representation` method calls `data.all()` on the nested queryset. So you effectively need to make `data = data.filter(**your_filters)` before the method is called. Then you need to add your subclassed ListSerializer as the list_serializer_class on the meta of the nested serializer.

1. subclass ListSerializer, overwriting `to_representation` and then calling super
2. add subclassed ListSerializer as the meta `list_serializer_class` on the nested Serializer

Here is the relevant code for your sample.

```
class FilteredListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):

    def to_representation(self, data):
        data = data.filter(user=self.context['request'].user, edition__hide=False)
        return super(FilteredListSerializer, self).to_representation(data)


class EditionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        list_serializer_class = FilteredListSerializer
        model = Edition


class QuestionnaireSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    edition = EditionSerializer(read_only=True)
    company = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Questionnaire
```

Comment: That did the trick! Though in the end I decided my serializers were getting too complex and I refactored them all, forcing the client to run a few more api calls but vastly simplifying my app.

Comment: Trying to use this as a basis for a solution to a similar problem; not sure if it really merits its own question. How would I pass a var from `QuestionnaireSerializer` into the ListSerializer? To approximate, I need to filter by Edition's ID as well as Questionnaire's ID.

Comment: Inside to_representation, pick off the object from the child's relationship back to the parent. All you'd do is something like data[0].question, allowing you to work your way back. Seems a bit hacky, but should work. Keep in mind that the data should already be filtered based on its relationship to the parent ID.

Comment: This should be in the DRF documentation. Super useful thank you!

Comment: In my implementation, I'm getting `'FilteredListSerializer' object has no attribute 'request'` Anyone else getting the same?

Comment: How is this working without declaring the model in the EditionSerializer i just keep getting "missing Meta.model attribute" error with this

Comment: The model would need to be defined on the EditionSerializer. This code sample was just meant to show how things are glued together, but I'll make the change for clarity.

Comment: To answer @Dominooch you need to use self.context['request'] instead of self.request

Comment: Very useful, and it still allows for that field to be writeable if you need so, by implementing the create/update methods of the QuestionnaireSerializer.

Comment: For me it failed when I started to use pagination for my app. The pagination function gives back a list as data, which cannot be filtered. I don't know of any work-around...

Comment: Unfortunately, this still means that there is N+1 SQL queries executed. I've yet to find a way that does not do that.

Comment: I believe in python 3 it is now possible to replace `super(FilteredListSerializer, self)` with just `super()` as we're no longer writing code to support python 2.

Comment: `context['serializer'] = serializers.ClientSerializer(object, context={'request': self.request})` If you manually instantiate the serializers, don't forget to pass in the request context if you need access to the user.

Answer (score 58):

While all the above answers work, I find the use of Django's `Prefetch` object the easiest way of all.

Say a `Restaurant` obj has a lot of `MenuItem`s, some of which are `is_removed == True`, and you only want those that are not removed.

In `RestaurantViewSet`, do something like

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

queryset = Restaurant.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('menu_items', queryset=MenuItem.objects.filter(is_removed=False), to_attr='filtered_menu_items')
)
```

In `RestaurantSerializer`, do something like

```
class RestaurantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    menu_items = MenuItemSerializer(source='filtered_menu_items', many=True, read_only=True)
```

Comment: Great solution, I agree this is the best way to solve it.

Comment: This should be at the top. The current top solution filters the data with to_representation after it's already been pulled from the database.  This solution filters the data on the query and fetches it in a bulk request.  Way better for most cases.

Comment: Perfect solution! Worked for me.

Comment: this worked! except that i had to use the first argument of Prefetch the related name. and i removed to_attr completely

Comment: What if you have multiple fields that use the same serializer, some filtered some not? 
`prefetch_related` gives me `'field' lookup was already seen with a different queryset. You may need to adjust the ordering of your lookups.`

Comment: This only works if you're able to pass in a queryset to the serializer right? What if it's a nested serializer but you can't pass in a queryset or set an attribute?

Comment: definitely best way to solve it and more performant one as well

Answer (score 33):

Tested many solutions from SO and other places.

Found only one working solution for Django 2.0 + DRF 3.7.7.

Define a method in model which has nested class. Craft a filter that will fit your needs.

```
class Channel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    number = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def current_epg(self):
        return Epg.objects.filter(channel=self, end__gt=datetime.now()).order_by("end")[:6]


class Epg(models.Model):
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    end = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=800)
    channel = models.ForeignKey(Channel, related_name='onair', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

.

```
class EpgSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Epg
        fields = ('channel', 'start', 'end', 'title', 'description',)


class ChannelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    onair = EpgSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, source="current_epg")

    class Meta:
        model = Channel
        fields = ('number', 'name', 'onair',)
```

Pay attention to `source="current_epg"` and you'll get the point.

Comment: Yes! This comment leverages the ability of the source to be a function, which you define on the model, then you can take advantage of filtering in there! Cool!

Comment: is it possible to pass a string to the function under the class?

Comment: I only needed ordering of a manytomany relatedfield. Also tried many to many different solutions (pun intended). But this was the only solution that worked for me! Thanks!

Comment: Looks like this is more correct solution in terms of code philosophy of django than accepted answer. Django proposes ActiveModel ("fat models") approach, so filtering should be made on model level (or viewset level) and serialization should know nothing about business logic.

Comment: I like this approach

Answer (score 16):

I find it easier, and more straight forward, to use a `SerializerMethodField` on the serializer field you want to filter.

So you would do something like this.

```
class CarTypesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = CarType
        fields = '__all__'


class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    car_types = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_car_types(self, instance):
        # Filter using the Car model instance and the CarType's related_name
        # (which in this case defaults to car_types_set)
        car_types_instances = instance.car_types_set.filter(brand="Toyota")
        return CarTypesSerializer(car_types_instances, many=True).data
```

This saves you from having to create many overrides of the `serializers.ListSerializer` if you need different filtering criteria for different serializers.

It also has the extra benefit of seeing exactly what the filter does within the serializer instead of diving into a subclass definition.

Of course the downside is if you have a serializer with many nested objects that all need to be filtered in some way. It could cause the serializer code to greatly increase. It's up to you how you would like to filter.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great, but if you'd need to use prefetch related that will be ignored when using methodfield. I do wonder if there's away to still accomplish a prefetch?

Comment: This method using SerializerMethodField seems great, except that the data types of CarTypeSerializer won't be properly reflected in the CarSerializer metadata. If you are for instance using OpenAPI / swagger to autogenerate API documentation, this will not be ideal.

Answer (score 8):

> When a serializer is instantiated and many=True is passed, a
> ListSerializer instance will be created. The serializer class then
> becomes a child of the parent ListSerializer
>
> This method takes the target of the field as the value argument, and
> should return the representation that should be used to serialize the
> target. The value argument will typically be a model instance.
>
> **Below is the example of the nested serializer**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """ Here many=True is passed, So a ListSerializer instance will be 
     created"""
    system = SystemSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('system', 'name')

class FilteredListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    
    """Serializer to filter the active system, which is a boolen field in 
       System Model. The value argument to to_representation() method is 
      the model instance"""
    
    def to_representation(self, data):
        data = data.filter(system_active=True)
        return super(FilteredListSerializer, self).to_representation(data)

class SystemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    mac_id = serializers.CharField(source='id')
    system_name = serializers.CharField(source='name')
    serial_number = serializers.CharField(source='serial')

    class Meta:
        model = System
        list_serializer_class = FilteredListSerializer
        fields = (
            'mac_id', 'serial_number', 'system_name', 'system_active', 
        )
```

**In view:**

```
class SystemView(viewsets.GenericViewSet, viewsets.ViewSet):
    def retrieve(self, request, email=None):
        data = get_object_or_404(UserProfile.objects.all(), email=email)
        serializer = UserSerializer(data)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me, from **self.context['view']**, You can get the filter params inside the serializer and use it however you want.

```
class ShipmentDocumentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
       model = Document
       fields = ['id', 'created_date', 'consignment', 'document', 'org', 'title' ]

class ShipmentDocumentTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   documents = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

   class Meta:
       model = DocumentType
       fields = ['id', 'type', 'documents']

    def get_documents(self, instance):
        consignment_id=self.context['view'].kwargs['consignment_id']
        queryset = Document.objects.filter(consignment__id=consignment_id)
        return ShipmentDocumentSerializer(queryset, many=True).data
```

Comment: My problem with this method is that is ignores the "prefetch_related" I added to my manager and multiplies my database requests.