# Filter on nested serializer in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm building a serializer in django using the django rest framework. I need to filter the query set for a nested model.

I found [How do you filter a nested serializer in Django Rest Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28163556/), which seemed to have the answer, but when I implemented it there was no change in my data. The only difference I can see is that the serializer referencing the filtered list serializer has other fields as well.

The models (abbreviated for clarity):

```
class GCUser(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()
    is_member = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    age = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    session_key = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True, blank=True, null=True)


class Connection(models.Model):
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(GCUser, related_name='user_connection')
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, related_name='event_connection')
    role = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=constants.Roles.ROLE_CHOICES,)

class Event(Game):
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    public = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    gm_is_player = models.BooleanField(default=False,
                                       help_text='Check if GM will be playing the game',
                                       verbose_name='GM is a player')
    gm_is_designer = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Check if GM designed the game')
    user_notes = models.TextField(blank=True, default='', verbose_name='Note to Scheduler')
    scheduler_notes = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
    experience = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=constants.ExpLevels.EXPERIENCE_CHOICES,
                                  default=constants.ExpLevels.NOVICE,)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=4, db_index=True,
                              choices=constants.Status.STATUS_CHOICES,)
```

Here's my code:

```
class FilteredListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, data):
        data = data.filter(status=constants.Status.ASSIGNED).order_by('start_time')
        return super(FilteredListSerializer, self).to_representation(data)


class UserEventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        list_serializer_class = FilteredListSerializer
        model = models.Event
        fields = ('id', 'event_name', 'conflict_type', 'start_time', 'end_time')


class UserConnectionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    event = UserEventSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = models.Connection
        fields = ('get_role_display', 'conflict_type', 'event')


class GCUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_connection = UserConnectionSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.GCUser
        fields = ('pk', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email',
                  'is_member', 'age', 'user_connection')
```

PyCharm tells me that "class FilteredListSerializer must implement all abstract methods" but it doesn't actually throw an error. I put a breakpoint at the first line of the list serializer, but it doesn't get tripped.

I'm using Python 3.4 with django 1.7.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Edited to add: Looking into the serializer code, I realized what may be the key difference: my call has `many=True`, whereas the one from the previous post didn't. I tried taking out the `model=`, but as expected that threw an error, so apparently the "working" code in the earlier post didn't actually run as written.

Comment: From your example it seems as though there isn't a model that is being nested for serialization. Could you explain which related model you want to be filtering and serializing?

Comment: I've edited the OP to include the models and the entire chain of serializers.

Comment: I had the same problem just now. Initially when i wrote my serializer the abstract warning was not there but today it is. I don't know how it fixed it but I ran invalidate cache and restart on pycharm and the warning went away..

Answer (score 2):

So I am not sure how to use the method you are using, but, if I understand your question correctly, I believe you could do something like this:

```
  class UserEventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
      model = models.Event
      fields = ('id', 'event_name', 'conflict_type', 'start_time', 'end_time')

  class UserConnectionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    event = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = models.Connection
        fields = ('get_role_display', 'conflict_type', 'event')

    def get_event(self, obj):
      if obj.event.status == constants.Status.ASSIGNED:
        serializer = UserEventSerializer(obj.event)
        return serializer.data
      else:
        serializer = UserEventSerializer(None)
        return serializer.data
```

N.B. This assumes that you are trying to exclude Events from being serialized if their status is not assigned.

I hope this helps. If I didn't understand the problem, let me know.

Comment: Sadly no, I'm still seeing events with status other than Assigned. I do think you understand the problem. I can see what your code is intended to do, and it is what I want.

Comment: Looking at it again, I realized that I missed one of the changes you proposed. Putting it in resulted in the following:

Exception Type:  AssertionError

Exception Value:  It is redundant to specify 'get_event' on SerializerMethodField 'event' in serializer 'UserConnectionSerializer', because it is the same as the default method name. Remove the 'method_name' argument.

Comment: I edited my answer to remove the 'method_name' argument, do the changes work?

Comment: It functioned, but it was still showing all the events that weren't assigned but with nulls for all fields. I took out the else clause calling the serializer with None and just returned None if the event wasn't assigned 

Those events still show up, but with the event as None rather than an object filled with nulls. It's not ideal, but it is an improvement.

Now if only I could get them sorted  by start time...

Answer (score 0):

it's not a bug or error. `ModelSerializer` has got already implemented all needed methods (most inhereted from `Serializer` class), but `ListSerializer` inherits from `BaseSerializer` and got implemented e.g.: `.create()` or `.to_representation()`, but not `.update()`. I've got some similar problems in PyCharm, when subclassing a `Serializer`. After implementing create, update and to_representation methods this issue was gone