# How to apply an extra filter to nested serializer with Django REST Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am building a serializer that has to deal with a nested many-to-many field. I got the chain of serializers set up, but it doesn't quite do what I need. It creates JSON that looks something like this:

```
"course_section": {
    "id": 6,
    "periods": [
        {
            "id": 3, 
            "coursemeet_set": [
                {
                    "id": 4, 
                    "period": 3, 
                    "course_section": 9,
                }, 
                {
                    "id": 8, 
                    "period": 3, 
                    "course_section": 6
                }, 
                {
                    "id": 9,
                    "period": 3, 
                    "course_section": 6
                },
            ], 
            "name": "Second Period"
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I'd expect Django REST Framework to output - all CourseMeets that match period `3` are displayed. However, in the case of this JSON output above, the course_section in which the set is nested has the ID of 6, so I'd only need the coursemeets that have `"course_section": 6` inside of them.

I spent some time with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28163556/945370), and I was able to create a custom ListSerializer that almost does what I want:

```
class FilteredCourseMeetSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, data):
        data = data.filter(period=3, course_section=6)
        return super(FilteredCourseMeetSerializer, self).to_representation(data)

class CourseMeetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CourseMeet
        list_serializer_class = FilteredCourseMeetSerializer

class PeriodSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    coursemeet_set = CourseMeetSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Period

class SectionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    periods = PeriodSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CourseSection
```

But, as you can see, I manually add the `period` and `course_section` filters to `data.filter`, and I would need to be able to pass those based on the id in SectionSerializer as well as the ID in PeriodSerializer.

How do I achieve this? Am I even on the right track with a ListSerializer or is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to solve this for one `CourseSection` per request, or you want to return a list of `CourseSection`'s per request?

Comment: @Todor Heh, `SectionSerializer` is actually called by another serializer. So, I am ending up with a list of CourseSections.