# Django REST; use queryset on a manytomany field to filter that related field

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am using the Django REST framework and cannot figure out how to filter the results of a subfield (manytomany field) that return when the referencing model/view is queried.

I have a Tag model that is related to a Book model via a manytomany field. When querying for tags it returns all the book associated with it. However, I need to filter the books to only include Books that the current user has access to.

I *can* get this filtered properly in the Book view, but I cannot figure out how to get this working for the tag view

```py
// Book model:
class BookQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def visible_to(self, user):
        if user.can_see_secrets:
            return self
        return self.exclude(secret_book=True)


class Book(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='Id', primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(db_column='CatalogNumber', unique=True, max_length=50)
    secret_book = models.IntegerField(db_column='secret', default=False)
    objects = BookQuerySet.as_manager()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'book'
        app_label = 'core'


// Book view:
class BooksFilteringBackend(filters.BaseFilterBackend):
    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        current_user = request.user
        queryset = queryset.visible_to(current_user)
        return queryset

class BookViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    filter_backends = (BooksFilteringBackend,)
    serializer_class = BookSerializer

There is a BookSerializer that doesnt do anything interesting
```

Now the above works, if a user queries the book view they only get the books they should be able to see.

Here is my issue:

```py
// Tag model
class Tag(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='Id', primary_key=True)
    description = models.CharField(db_column='Description', unique=True, max_length=255)
    books = models.ManyToManyField('core.Book', through='BookTag', related_name='tags')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tag'
        app_label = 'tags'

// Tag viewset
class TagViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Tag.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TagSerializer

// Tag serializer
class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    description = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
    books = BookSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ('id',
                  'description',
                  'books',)
```

If I hit the tag viewset, i get all books associated with the tag, because i am not filtering the books out based on the same logic above.
How can I make it so when I pull tags, i can make use of BookQuerySet or something similar.

Appreciate any insights!

Comment: Are you looking for nested routes?

Comment: @schillingt Mind elaborating on that? I'm not sure what is exactly.

Comment: Basically `/book/1/tags/a-tag/` where you have a view set for Book and then another view set that assumes there's a book kwarg in the url to filter down to.

Comment: If you only want to optionally filter by some ForeignKey, then I'd recommend looking into django-filter (https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/rest_framework.html)

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer: [How do you filter a nested serializer in Django Rest Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28163556/how-do-you-filter-a-nested-serializer-in-django-rest-framework)

The trick is to do this at the serializer level. Evidently where the tag serializer references the book serializer, the query for the books is all() so you can override that:

In my uninteresting book serializer file:

```py
// added:
class BookFilteredListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, data):
        data = data.visible_to(self.context['request'].user)
        return super(BookFilteredListSerializer, self).to_representation(data)

// And then reference this from the actual BookSerializer meta:
class WorkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

     ...

     class Meta:
         model = Work
         list_serializer_class = WorkFilteredListSerializer
         fields = (...)
```

Now the tag uses this filtering system when i query the tag endpoint and it loads in the works.