# Django REST: Exclude some fields and filter a nested serializer

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am trying to exclude the field "prospect" from the Appointment serializer, which is nested under the Unit Serializer.

As you can see below, due to some data manipulation on the Appointment queryset, I decided to use a SerializerMethodField to define the Appointment serializer. However, I am not sure how to exclude fields when using a SerializerMethodField.

Alternatively, I could use a ModelSerializer for the Appointment, which allows me to define which fields to include, but then I would not be able to manipulate the data the way I want.

Note sure what to do.

**Models**

```
class Appointment(models.Model):
    appointment_time = models.DateTimeField()
    unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    staff = models.ForeignKey(Staff, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    prospect = models.ForeignKey(Prospect, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Serializers**

```
class UnitSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    availability = SerializerMethodField()
    manager = ManagerSerializer()
    instruction = InstructionSerializer(source='instruction_set', many=True)
    appointment = SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Unit
        fields = ['id', 'address', 'manager', 'availability', 'instruction', 'appointment']

    def get_availability(self, instance): 
        queryset = instance.availability_set.order_by('start_time')
        return AvailabilitySerializer(queryset, many=True).data

    def get_appointment(self, instance):
        start_buffer = 0.5 ## How many hours from now do we start displaying appointments in the queue
        end_buffer = 72 ## How many hours from now do we stop displaying appointments in the queue
        start_cutoff = datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=start_buffer)
        end_cutoff = datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=end_buffer)
        queryset = instance.appointment_set.exclude(appointment_time__lt=start_cutoff).exclude(appointment_time__gt=end_cutoff).order_by('appointment_time')
        return AppointmentSerializer(queryset, many=True).data
```

**JSON Object Representation**

[image: AJAX Call]

Comment: Just make a specific `AppointmentSerializer` (like `UnitAppointmentSerializer` where you exclude these fields).

Comment: You can subclass from your original serializer, and thus make a modified serializer, but with the original one as "base".

Comment: @ Willem Van Onsem  But how would I modify the data from the ```AppointmentSerializer```? I was thinking of creating a new field called filtered_appointments as a SerializerMethodField(), then write the filtering method under the Appointment model. Does that make sense?

Comment: well here it looks rather odd to make changes since you first *filter* the queryset. But I think it is better here to use a subserializer, not a method: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/

Comment: Alright, after a bit more research, I found out how to solve this. I think you were referring to using "subclass". In this case, I subclassed a ListSerializer and overwrote the to_representation method. Pretty well explained in this discussion : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28163556/how-do-you-filter-a-nested-serializer-in-django-rest-framework