# Apply filter on data in nested serializer in Django-rest-framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have two model for handle Articles and article Comments

Article model:

```
class Articles(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, allow_unicode=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    body = models.TextField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Comment model:

```
class Comments(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(
        Articles, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    reply = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True, default=False)
```

also I have these serializers for article:

Article serializer:

```
class ArticlesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    alt_cover = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    owner = UserSerializer()
    comments_set = CommentsSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Articles
        fields = "__all__"

    def get_alt_cover(self, obj):
        return str(obj.cover)
```

Comment serializer:

```
class CommentsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Comments
        fields = "__all__"
```

the main problem is I have two type comment: 1 accepted   2 not accepted  (status field)
I want to get just accepted comments (status = True)
where should I apply filter for comments?
if you pay attention to `comments_set = CommentsSerializer(many=True)` I'm getting comments with this trick

I have test `to_representation` like this:

```
def to_representation(self, data):
        data = data.filter(status=True)
        return super(CommentsSerializer, self).to_representation(data)
```

but I got this error: 'Comments' object has no attribute 'filter'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you filter a nested serializer in Django Rest Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28163556/how-do-you-filter-a-nested-serializer-in-django-rest-framework)