# How to remove instances inside serializer

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Here inside the serializer using to_representation, validate to remove the instance that doesn't satisfy the condition "completed == total_videos" but gets all the instances, so please suggest a solution to fix this

```
class LearnerVideoMarkUsCompleteMyCourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    course = CourseSerializerForEnrolledCourseService()
    total_videos = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    completed = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    id = serializers.UUIDField(source="course.id")

    def get_total_videos(self, data):
        total_video_count = VideoDetails.objects.filter(
            video__coursemodulevideos__module_id__coursesectionmodule__section_id__coursesectiondetails__course=data.course
        ).count()
        return total_video_count

    def get_completed(self, data):
        progress = data.learner.learner_video_markascomplete.filter(
            course=data.course, mark_us_complete=True
        ).count()
        return progress

    class Meta:
        model = LearnerVideoMarkUsComplete
        fields = ("course", "id", "completed", "total_videos")

    def validate(self, data):
        completed = self.get_completed(data)
        total_videos = self.get_total_videos(data)

        print("complete", completed)
        print("total_videos", total_videos)

        if completed == total_videos:
            return data
        else:
            return "not equal"

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        completed = self.get_completed(instance)
        total_videos = self.get_total_videos(instance)

        if completed == total_videos:
            return super().to_representation(instance)
        else:
            return None
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use a custom `ListSerializer` class and override the `to_representation` method to filter out the instances that do not meet your condition. You can then specify this class as the `list_serializer_class` in the `Meta` class of your serializer. This way, you can control the output of the nested serializer without modifying the `validate` method.

Here is an example of how you can implement this solution:

```
class FilteredListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, data):
       data = data.filter(completed=F('total_videos'))
       return super().to_representation(data)

class LearnerVideoMarkUsCompleteMyCourseSerializer(
            serializers.ModelSerializer):
    course = CourseSerializerForEnrolledCourseService()
    total_videos = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    completed = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    id = serializers.UUIDField(source="course.id")

    def get_total_videos(self, data):
        total_video_count = VideoDetails.objects.filter(
        video__coursemodulevideos__module_id__coursesectionmodule__section_id__coursesectiondetails__course=data.course
    ).count()
    return total_video_count

     def get_completed(self, data):
         progress = data.learner.learner_video_markascomplete.filter(
        course=data.course, mark_us_complete=True
        ).count()
        return progress

      class Meta:
          model = LearnerVideoMarkUsComplete
          fields = ("course", "id", "completed", "total_videos")
          list_serializer_class = FilteredListSerializer
```

I hope this helps you. For more information, you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28163556/how-do-you-filter-a-nested-serializer-in-django-rest-framework) which explains how to filter a nested serializer in the Django Rest Framework.

Comment: Here "completed", "total_videos" are not the model fields, which are calculated data inside the serializer, so how to use these data inside FilteredListSerializer