# Django Getting a List of Items from one Model and using it to filter another

Tags: python, django

So, I have 3 tables in my model, house, room, and item.  room contains a foreign key to house, and item contains a foreign key to room.  I want to be able to query by the house and get all the items in the house.

```
class room(models.Model):
    house= models.ForeignKey(house, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class house (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, null=False)  #House name, unique
    houseCode = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=False)  # house code

class item(models.Model):
    room= models.ForeignKey(room, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)  # ForeignKey to room
    itemName = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)  # item



So I want to be able to pass in a house ID and get all the associated items in the house, grouped by rooms, so the desired return would be something like.

{
room:living room,
   items:[couch, tv]
room: bedroom,
   items:[bed, nightstand]
}
```

Not sure what I need in the new serializer/view to be able to do this as all my current serializers/views are just the model and all fields for basic CRUD operations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you filter a nested serializer in Django Rest Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28163556/how-do-you-filter-a-nested-serializer-in-django-rest-framework)