# Filter on Nested serializer - Django REST

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, nested

I have the following `models.py`:

```
class Question(models.Model):

    code = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    catgeroy = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True, db_index=True, related_name='category')


class Answer(models.Model):

    question = models.ForeignKey(
        Question, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True, db_index=True, related_name='question')
    exam = models.ForeignKey(Exam, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)


class Exam(models.Model):

    year = models.IntegerField()
```

my nested `serializer` looks like this:

```
class AnswerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    related_name = 'answer'

    class Meta:
        model = Value
        fields = ('id', 'value', 'question', 'exam')


class NestedQuestionAnswerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    answer = AnswerSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = (
            'id','code', 'text', 'answer'
        )
```

my `views.py` looks like this:

```
class QuestionAnswerViewSet(BaseCertViewSet):
    queryset = Question.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.NestedQuestionAnswerSerializer
    filter_backends = [filters.DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ('category',)
```

my `urls.py` looks like this:

```
router.register('question-answer', views.QuestionAnswerViewSet, 'question-answer')
```

**What I would like to be able to do is to filter by both Category AND Exam**(which is a child attribute). So something like this: `https://example.com/api/question-answer?category=4&exam=21`

This potentially *should* return all the Questions that are part of category=4 AND appeared on exam=21.

I have no problem filtering by `category` alone, but can't seem to filter on `exam` which is a child foreign key.

I've tried many solutions on SO but none seem to do the above.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks everyone for your suggested solutions.

I ended up using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42156901/filtered-nested-relationships-django-rest-framework)

Added a List Serializer class and modified the `to_representation` function:

```
class FilteredAnswerSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, data):
        qry_exam = self.context['request'].GET.get('exam')
        data = data.filter(exam=qry_exam)
        return super(FilteredAnswerSerializer,  self).to_representation(data)
```

and then in my Answer serializer I call it:

```
class AnswerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    related_name = 'answer'

    class Meta:
        model = Value

        list_serializer_class = FilteredAnswerSerializer

        fields = ('id', 'value', 'question', 'exam')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your suggested solutions.

I ended up using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42156901/filtered-nested-relationships-django-rest-framework)

Added a List Serializer class and modified the `to_representation` function:

```
class FilteredAnswerSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, data):
        qry_exam = self.context['request'].GET.get('exam')
        data = data.filter(exam=qry_exam)
        return super(FilteredAnswerSerializer,  self).to_representation(data)
```

and then in my Answer serializer I call it:

```
class AnswerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    related_name = 'answer'

    class Meta:
        model = Value

        list_serializer_class = FilteredAnswerSerializer

        fields = ('id', 'value', 'question', 'exam')
```

I will update my question with the solution.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it would be to [create a custom `FilterSet` for the `ViewSet` using **django-filter**](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/rest_framework.html).

That is the more readable, and preferred way of doing it, since the code will be clearer and easier to alter in the future.

A very simple, less extendable way of achieving this would be to [override the `get_queryset` method of the `ViewSet` class](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/).

```py
from django.db.models import Prefetch

class NestedQuestionAnswerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    answer = AnswerSerializer(source="filtered_answers", many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('id', 'code', 'text', 'answer')

class QuestionAnswerViewSet(BaseCertViewSet):
    queryset = Question.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.NestedQuestionAnswerSerializer
    filter_backends = [filters.DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ('category',)

    def get_exam_param(self):
        """ A helper to extract the exam id from the query_params. """
        try:
            return int(self.request.query_params["exam"])
        except (KeyError, ValueError, TypeError):
            return None

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        exam = self.get_exam_param()
        if exam is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(answer__exam_id=exam).prefetch_related(
                Prefetch(
                    "answers",
                    queryset=Answer.objects.filter(exam_id=exam),
                    to_attr="filtered_answers",
                ),
            )
        else:
            queryset = queryset.prefetch_related(
                Prefetch(
                    "answers",
                    queryset=Answer.objects.all(),
                    to_attr="filtered_answers",
                ),
            )
        return queryset
```

***Edit***: Added `filtered_answers` to `get_queryset` and serializer class based on
updated understanding of question from comments. Mostly adapted from [this answer
here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58689019/28360).

Comment: Thanks but `queryset = queryset.filter(answer__exam_id=int(exam))` does not seem to work. No errors but it does not filter out the results by exam.

Comment: What is the value of `exam`?

Comment: I highly recommend django-filter. It'll make your life so much easier.

Comment: @damon - it is an integer representing the exam_id - I've tried your solution and also some similar variations of it but that does not filter the nested serializer - instead, the query returns all Answers for a Question

Comment: @kloster Ah, I see what you're looking to do now. My queryset will return all `Question` objects that have `answer` objects with `exam_id=query_params["exam"]`. What you _actually_ want, is the same queryset, but also for the **serializer** to only display the `Answer` objects that have `exam_id=...`. That's slightly different.

Comment: @kloster I've updated my answer to _hopefully_ satisfy your question's requirements. I have not tested the code, so it may need tweaking.

Comment: I tried above but this gives the following error: `'QuestionAnswerViewSet' object has no attribute 'exam_param'`

Comment: Oops, that should've been `self.get_exam_param()`. I updated the example, but it looks like you've found an answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

you can create the filter class, in that filter class you can write down the custom fields and their query.

```
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters
class QuestionFilter(filters.FilterSet):
   exam = filters.IntegerField(method="filter_exam")

  class Meta:
       fields = ('category', 'exam')

  def filter_exam(self, queryset, name, value):
     return queryset.filter(answer__exam_id=value)
```

in view

```
class QuestionAnswerViewSet(BaseCertViewSet):
    queryset = Question.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.NestedQuestionAnswerSerializer
    filter_backends = [filters.DjangoFilterBackend]
    filter_class = QuestionFilter
```