# Django Rest Filterset - how to filter by nested serializer?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Good evening colleagues! I have the following code:

serializators.py

```
class CoinCostsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('price', 'timestamp',)
        model = CoinCosts

class CoinSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('symbol', 'crr', 'costs')
        model = Coins
    costs = CoinCostsSerializer(source='coincosts_set.all', many=True)
```

views.py

```
class CoinCostFilterSet(filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = Coins
        fields = {
            'symbol': ['exact'],
        }


class CoinCostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Coins.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CoinSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_class = CoinCostFilterSet
```

models.py

```
class Coins(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    crr = models.CharField(max_length=3)

class CoinCosts(models.Model):
    coin_id = models.ForeignKey(Coins, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    crr = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    volume = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=4)
    reserve = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=4)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=4)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

And by typing the address

```
/CoinCost/?symbol=ZERO
```

for example, I have filtering from Django on this coin.

So i need this url:

```
/CoinCost/?symbol=ZERO&timestamp_start=2019-12-14T00:00:00&timestamp_end=2019-12-17T00:00:00
```

- get filtering not only by Zero coin but also by Timestamp. Can you help? What should my code look like for this task? How do I filter by the embedded serializer as well?

I see this [Filtered Nested Relationships Django Rest Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42156901/filtered-nested-relationships-django-rest-framework) but> no work, i have 2  nested fields in serializer - timestamp and costs

Thanks for the help! Have a good weekend!

Comment: Igor, show your models as well

Comment: added models.py

Comment: Igor, usually, developers use singular names for tables, like Coin and CoinCost

Comment: yes, thank  you, i edit tomorrow )

Answer (score 1):

[Filtering across relationships](https://github.com/philipn/django-rest-framework-filters#filtering-across-relationships) for Django `1.11` and `2.x`

```
import rest_framework_filters as filters
from rest_framework_filters import IsoDateTimeFilter


class CoinFilterSet(filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = Coins
        fields = {
            'symbol': ('exact', 'in', 'startswith', 'endswith', 'contains')}


class CoinCostFilterSet(filters.FilterSet):
    coin = filters.RelatedFilter(
        CoinFilterSet, queryset=Coins.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = CoinCosts
        fields = {
            'timestamp': ('exact', 'in', 'gt', 'gte', 'lt', 'lte')}
        filter_overrides = {
            DateTimeField: {'filter_class': IsoDateTimeFilter}}
```

Use these filters for such queries

```
/CoinCost/?coin__symbol=ZERO&timestamp__gte=2019-12-14T00:00:00&timestamp__lte=2019-12-17T00:00:00
```

Comment: Good! But i use Django 3 and this version no supported in you module. More error ImportError: cannot import name 'six' and i see this module work i only Django <2

Comment: Igor, you can use this Python package up to Django 2.2

Comment: Igor, just use Django 2 now, it will not have benefits in your case, only problems