# Filtering nested resources Django REST Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

At the begining I want to say that I found partial answer for my question([How can I apply a filter to a nested resource in Django REST framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16821684/how-can-i-apply-a-filter-to-a-nested-resource-in-django-rest-framework)), but its not cover my problem in 100%.

I have nested 3 models:

### - ModelA

### -- ModelAB

### ---- ModelB

I need get all ModelA filtering over ModelB but I need also that ModelB will be filtered.

Ex. /modelA?modelab__modelb__id=100

It need returned values:

```
[{id:1,
    modelab: [{
        id:10
        modelb{
          id: 100
        }]
    }]
}]
```

but it return

```
[{id:1,
    modelab: [{
        id:10
        modelb{
          id: 100
        },
        id:11
        modelb{
          id: 102
        }]
    }]
}]
```

So it's only filtering on first level of nesting. I want to that applied filter will be applied for all nested models.

My code:

```
// models.py
class ModelA(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
class ModelB(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
class ModelAB(models.Model):
    modelA = models.ForeignKey(ModelA)
    modelB = models.ForeignKey(ModelB)
    type_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)

// views.py
class ModelAFilter(filters.FilterSet):

    vacancy_id = Filter(name="vacancy__id")
    class Meta:
        model = Candidate
        fields = ('name', 'modelAB__modelB__name')

class ModelAViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ModelA.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ModelASerializer

    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, )
    filter_class = ModelFilter

// serializers.py
class ModelBSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    modelB = ModelB(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ModelB
        fields = ('id', 'name')

class ModelABSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    modelB= ModelBSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ModelB
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'modelB',)

class ModelASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    modelAB = ModelAB(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'modelAB')
```

Comment: add the code you are using in the question

Comment: Added code and change naming

Answer (score 1):

You have to override the `get_queryset` method on your viewset and filter the `prefetch_related` query:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    # get the filter value
    modelb_id = self.request.query_params.get('modelab__modelb__id', None)
    queryset_modelab = ModelAB.objects.all()
    # you can use django-filter class here too
    if modelb_id:
        queryset_modelab = queryset_modelab.filter(modelb_id=modelb_id)
    queryset_modelab.select_related('modelb')
    queryset = (ModelA.objects
                .prefetch_related(
                    Prefetch('modelab_set', queryset=queryset_modelab))
                .all())
    # modela filter class will work on this queryset
    return queryset
```

Comment: I was thinking about but what when it dosent have filter or when will be more fields to filter? I need to check if they exist... I was thinking if is any dynamic way to do this. In SQLAlchemy I could done it with eager_loading

Comment: yes, definitely you will have to check if the filter is present or not. I will edit the answer a bit for more clarity.