# Django REST framework: filter nested objects by currently logged in owner

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to filter nested objects in API response by the ownership of currently authorized user.

Here is my setup:
Django 1.8, Django REST framework 3.

#### MODELS

```
class Container(models.Model):
  container_title = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

class Item(models.Model):
  item_title = models.CharField(max_length = 50, blank = True, null = True, default = " ")
  item_container = models.ForeignKey(Container, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name = 'all_items_in_container')

class Notification(models.Model):
  owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', null = True, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
  item_to_track = models.ForeignKey(Container, default = False, blank = True, null = True, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name = 'notifications_for_container')
```

#### SERIALIZERS

```
class ItemsSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Item
    fields = ('pk', 'item_title')

class NotificationSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
  owner = serializers.IntegerField(source='owner.pk')
  class Meta:
    model = Notification
    fields = ('pk', 'owner')

class ContainerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  all_items_in_container = ItemsSerializer(many=True)
  #notifications_for_container = NotificationSerializer(many = True)  # this line returns all existing notifications per Container

  notifications_for_container = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_current_user_notifications')

  def get_current_user_notifications(self, obj):
    user = self.context['request'].user
    user_notifications = Notification.objects.filter(item_to_track=obj, owner=user)
    serializer = NotificationSerializer(user_notifications)
    return serializer.data

  class Meta:
    model = Container
    fields = ('notifications_for_container', 'pk', 'container_title', 'all_items_in_container')
```

#### DRF VIEW

```
class ContainerViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):

    queryset = Container.objects.all()

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      queryset = self.queryset
      serializer = ContainerSerializer(data = [], many = True,  context={'request': request})

      if serializer.is_valid():
        new_serializer = ContainerSerializer(queryset, many = True, context={'request': request})
        data = new_serializer.data[:]

      return Response({'data':data})


    def retrieve(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
      queryset = self.get_queryset()

      try:
        holder = Container.objects.get(pk=pk)
      except Container.DoesNotExist:
        holder = False

      if holder:
        serializer = ContainerSerializer(holder, context={'request': request})
        data = serializer.data

        return Response({'data':data})
```

Different users can create Notification objects for the same Container.

If i uncomment `#notifications_for_container = NotificationSerializer(many = True)`, I'll get:

```
"data": [
    {
      "notifications_for_container": [
        {
          "pk": 11,
          "owner": 2,
        },
        {
          "pk": 20,
          "owner": 46,
        }
      ],
      "pk": 6,
      "container_title": "TEST CONTAINER",
      "all_items_in_holder": [
        {
          "pk": 12,
          "item_title": "xbox1 from amazon ",
        },
      ]
     }
    ]
```

no matter under which user I'm currently logged in.

What I'm trying to achieve here, is to return only owner's Notification in `notifications_for_container` section of API response.

Eg if I'm logged in as user with `pk=2`, I should get only

```
"data": [
    {
      "notifications_for_container": [
        {
          "pk": 11,
          "owner": 2,
        }
      ]
...
...
```

I've been trying to implement the solution from [How can I apply a filter to a nested resource in Django REST framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16821684/how-can-i-apply-a-filter-to-a-nested-resource-in-django-rest-framework), but I'm getting `KeyError at /api/containers/ 'request'`

I've been trying to solve this problem for 2 days already and maybe I don't see something obvious, so any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first:

```
serializer = ContainerSerializer(many=True, context={'request': request})
```

or

```
serializer = ContainerSerializer(many=True, context=self.get_serializer_context())
```

second:

```
def get_current_user_notifications(self, obj):
    user = self.context['request'].user
    # user_notifications  is a queryset
    user_notifications = Notification.objects.filter(item_to_track=obj, owner=user) 
    # so you need add many=True
    serializer = NotificationSerializer(user_notifications, many=True)
    return serializer.data
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code seems to be that the `context` attribute is not being populated with the current request. Take a look at [Including extra context](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context). Probably you should be doing something like:

```
     serializer = ContainerSerializer(many=True, context={'request': request})
```

Comment: It is hard to tell, what file has the statement `serializer = NotificationSerializerForItemsHolder(user_notifications)`? Is it possible to post your full traceback?

Comment: Pardon, my mistake, here is the full error text:
`AttributeError at /api/containers/
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field 'owner' on serializer 'NotificationSerializer'.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the 'QuerySet' instance.
Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'owner'.`

Comment: Perhaps you should try to change `source='owner.pk'` to just `source='pk'`

Comment: Nope, it didn't help.
it definitely fails on line `serializer = NotificationSerializerForItemsHolder(user_notifications)` but I cannot understand why.


i get this in the traceback: 


myproj/api_app/views.py" in list
  107.         data = new_serializer.data


myproj/api_app/serializers.py" in get_current_user_notifications
  101.     return serializer.data

Comment: Try to update the question with the full traceback. Reproducing the problem based on the information you posted is a lot of work and I lack the time (and lets be honest, the will) to do this properly but I can take a look at the **full trace** if you update your question with it.

Comment: BTW, what happens if you comment the line `owner = serializers.IntegerField(source='owner.pk')`?

Comment: thank you for your patience. I think I've just found the solution: it seems `get_current_user_notifications` should contain the line `serializer = NotificationSerializer(user_notifications, many=True)`  I'll update the question tomorrow after lunch CEST