# django-filter and DRF: AND clause in a lookupfield

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

This question expands on [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14749530/django-rest-framework-filter-many-to-many-field).

Suppose my models are

```
class Car(models.Model):
    images = models.ManyToManyField(Image)

class Image(models.Model):
    path = models.CharField()
    type = models.CharField()
```

and my filter class is

```
class CarFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    having_image = django_filters.Filter(name="images", lookup_type='in')

    class Meta:
        model = Car
```

then I can make GET queries like `?having_image=5` and get all cars that have an image with `pk=5`. That's fine. But what if I need to return both cars with this image AND also cars with no images at all, in one list? How do I unite two conditions in one `django_filters.Filter`?

Comment: you might find your answer in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41194200/django-filter-with-drf-how-to-do-and-when-applying-multiple-values-with-the answer. please take a look and let me know if you still have doubts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's supported out of the box with django-filter. You could try to create your own Filter class and override the `filter()` method.

Querysets do support the `|` (union) operator, so you can combine the default result with the results where the field result is `None`.

```
class AndNoneFilter(django_filters.Filter):

    def filter(self, qs, value):
        return qs(**{self.field_name: None}) | super().filter(qs, value)

class CarFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    having_image = AndNoneFilter(field_name='images', lookup_type='in')
```

I've not tested this code, so it might not work exactly as written, but you get the idea.