# Filter many-to-many field DRF

Tags: django, filter, django-rest-framework

I need to filter my API response of document using a many-to-many category field. This is my model:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank = True)
    file = models.FileField(null = True, upload_to='documents/', validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['pdf'])])
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, null = True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, null = True, on_delete = models.SET_NULL)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Employee, null = True, on_delete = models.SET_NULL)
```

The serializer for this models is:

```
class DocumentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = "__all__"
```

And I'm trying to filter it with this:

```
class DocumentFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    # having_category = filters.Filter(name = 'category', lookup_type = 'in')
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = {
            'company': ['exact'],
            'author': ['exact'],
            # 'category': ['in']
        }
```

I tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26915276/9682023) solution as you can see in the code but wasn't successful.
filtering with company and author are working, and I'm facing an issue only with category.

How should I create the filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can refer from here https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html

```
import django_filters

class DocumentFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    company = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr="exact", field_name='company__name')
    author = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr="exact", field_name='author__name')
    category = django_filters.CharFilter(method='filter_category')

    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = ['company', 'author', 'category']

    def filter_category(self, queryset, name, value):
        categories = value.split(',')
        return queryset.filter(category__name__in=categories)
```

Comment: Happy To Helppp

Answer (score 0):

refer to [here](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/main/ref/filters.html#baseinfilter)

```
import django_filters as filters

class CharInFilter(filters.BaseInFilter, filters.CharFilter):
    pass

class DocumentFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    category_in = CharInFilter(field_name='category__name', lookup_expr='in', distinct=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = {
            'company': ['iexact'],
            'author': ['iexact'],
         }
```